# Condition in WHERE clause (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I need a query which returns data based on what month/year it is. Below is a subquery i wrote which returns one row - start_date and end_date are the values i need to use in my main query

```
WITH SUBQ AS (SELECT 
    dim.MONTH_NAME as current_month_name
   ,dim.year_period as current_month
   ,dim.PERIOD_YEAR as YEAR
   ,CASE WHEN dim.year_period NOT LIKE '%01' THEN to_number(CONCAT(to_char(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-1) , '01' ))
         WHEN dim.year_period LIKE '%01'THEN to_number(CONCAT(to_char(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-2) , '01' ))
         END AS START_DATE 
   ,CASE WHEN dim.year_period NOT LIKE '%01' THEN to_number(CONCAT(to_char(dim.PERIOD_YEAR) , '01'  ))
         WHEN dim.year_period LIKE '%01'THEN to_number(CONCAT(to_char(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-1) , '01'   )) END AS ENDDATE 
  from dim_periods dim    WHERE dim.year_period=to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'YYYYMM')))
```

Question is - how do i use values from subquery with one row in where clauses?
I need to get something like this, i just dont understand how should i join my subquery and the rest of the tables i use -

```
select * from financial_data fd 
where fd.year_period BETWEEN subq.start_date and subq.enddate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join the **subquery**, i.e. the **CTE** with the table, and then use the column name in the **filter predicate**. The result of the subquery in the **WITH clause** acts like a **temporary table**.

For example,

```
WITH SUBQ AS
  (SELECT dim.MONTH_NAME AS current_month_name ,
    dim.year_period      AS current_month ,
    dim.PERIOD_YEAR      AS YEAR ,
    CASE
      WHEN dim.year_period NOT LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-1) , '01' ))
      WHEN dim.year_period LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-2) , '01' ))
    END AS START_DATE ,
    CASE
      WHEN dim.year_period NOT LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR) , '01' ))
      WHEN dim.year_period LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-1) , '01' ))
    END AS ENDDATE
  FROM dim_periods dim
  WHERE dim.year_period=to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM'))
  )
SELECT fd.COLUMNS,
  q.COLUMNS
FROM financial_data fd
JOIN subq q
ON (fd.KEY = q.KEY) -- join key
WHERE fd.year_period BETWEEN q.start_date AND q.enddate;
```

So, `SUBQ` acts like a temporary table, which you join with `financial_data` table.

**UPDATE** OP doesn't want the **ANSI join syntax**.

```
WITH SUBQ AS
  (SELECT dim.MONTH_NAME AS current_month_name ,
    dim.year_period      AS current_month ,
    dim.PERIOD_YEAR      AS YEAR ,
    CASE
      WHEN dim.year_period NOT LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-1) , '01' ))
      WHEN dim.year_period LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-2) , '01' ))
    END AS START_DATE ,
    CASE
      WHEN dim.year_period NOT LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR) , '01' ))
      WHEN dim.year_period LIKE '%01'
      THEN to_number(CONCAT(TO_CHAR(dim.PERIOD_YEAR-1) , '01' ))
    END AS ENDDATE
  FROM dim_periods dim
  WHERE dim.year_period=to_number(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYYMM'))
  )
SELECT fd.COLUMNS,
  q.COLUMNS
FROM financial_data fd,
  subq q
WHERE fd.KEY = q.KEY -- join key
AND fd.year_period BETWEEN q.start_date AND q.enddate;
```

Comment: Ok, but how do i do this with a join in WHERE clause?

Because if i try to do the following :
 fd.year_period=subq2.current_month
   AND fd.year_period between subq2.start_date and subq2.enddate i dont get any rows returned, i simply dont understand why

Comment: @user3014914 I provided you the ANSI syntax. See my update for the Oracle equivalent syntax.